# Serializing GenericRecord in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, avro

I have multiple independent source systems pushing AVRO events into different Kafka topics. A Flink kafka consumer must consume events from these topics as GenericRecord, and then use the GenericRecord in downstream operator. (I need a generic format of key/value pairs to work with).

Initially, I tried to serialize the GenericRecord Schema into a string and json payload into a string, and then rebuild the GenericRecord in downstream operator. However, this was too expensive as the Schema string is 3x or 4x bigger than the actual payload.

Now I'm converting each GenericRecord instance to key/value pairs in a Map<String, Object>. Flink is using Kryo by default given I have generic types but this is slow and wondering how I can improve it further. How can I serialize the GenericRecord in such a way that it can be serialized/ deserialized fast by Flink (and avoid having to pull the Schema throughout all downstream operators)?

Currently thinking of casting all values to String, hence end up with Map<String, String>, and then downcast the value (e.g., from String to decimal, etc) when the value is used, however, I'm running into difficulties with AVRO maps, lists, etc

What's the best solution to handle this scenario in Flink? Any other alternatives or suggestions?